# Kafka Error: Could not find or load main class org.apache.kafka.clients.tools.ProducerPerformance

Tags: apache-kafka, clj-kafka

I was trying to run Performance test as per the following article for Apache Kafka

Reference:

https://engineering.linkedin.com/kafka/benchmarking-apache-kafka-2-million-writes-second-three-cheap-machines

Linked-in tests: https://gist.github.com/jkreps/c7ddb4041ef62a900e6c

But when I run this:

```
 bin/kafka-run-class.sh org.apache.kafka.clients.tools.ProducerPerformance test7 50000000 100 -1 acks=1 bootstrap.servers=localhost:9092 buffer.memory=67108864 batch.size=8196
```

It shows the error:

```
Error: Could not find or load main class org.apache.kafka.clients.tools.ProducerPerformance
```

Is it about kafka version? Or I need to download the class from somewhere else?

Where is my  **org.apache.kafka.clients.tools.ProducerPerformance** class? Please suggest..

Answer (score 6):

Package name of `ProducerPerformance` has been changed from 
`org.apache.kafka.clients.tools` to `org.apache.kafka.tools`.

For more details, check my answer for a possible duplicate [question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38828745/1680826).

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to build the project first before running this command .. you can use build tool such as `sbt` as documented in their [official web site](http://kafka.apache.org/08/documentation.html)